# Combine Regex to match variations of a String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that I'd like to pull some content from using javascript. The string can have multiple forms as follows:

`[[(a*, b*) within 20]] or [[...(a*, b*) within 20]]` where the "..." may or may not exist.

I'd like a regex that will match the **"(a*, b*) within 20"** portion.

`/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/.exec(text)[1]` will match `[[(a*, b*) within 20]]`

and

`/([^\.]+)\]\]/.exec(text)[1]` will match `[[...(a*, b*) within 20]]`

How can I combine these so that both version of the text will match **"(a*, b*) within 20"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var m = s.match(/\[\[.*?(\([^)]*\).*?)\]\]/);
if (m)
    console.log(m[1]);
    // (a*, b*) within 20 for both input strings
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like a regex that will match the `(a*, b*) within 20` portion.

You can try

```
\[\[.*?(\(a\*, b\*\) .*?)\]\]
```

Here is demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mD6eY6)

**Note:** you can use `\w` or `[a-z]` to make it more precise as per your need instead of `a` and `b`

```
\[\[.*?(\w\*, \w\*\) .*?)\]\]
```

Here escape chracter `\` is used to escape special characters of regex pattern such as . [ [ ] ] * ( )

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match both variations.

```
\[\[[^(]*(\([^)]*\)[^\]]*)\]\]
```

**Explanation**:

```
\[            #   '['
\[            #   '['
[^(]*         #   any character except: '(' (0 or more times)
(             #   group and capture to \1:
  \(          #     '('
  [^)]*       #      any character except: ')' (0 or more times)
  \)          #     ')'
  [^\]]*      #     any character except: '\]' (0 or more  times)
)             #   end of \1
\]            #   ']'
\]            #   ']'
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/166702)